# Style a <label> based on its <input>'s state

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox

Is it possible, with only CSS, to style an HTML label dependent on its input's state?

In my case, I want to style an `<input type="checkbox">` based on whether it's checked.

I tried putting the label inside the input, but Firefox and Chrome (at least) seems to parse them as siblings, even though they're clearly nested in the input source.  And I don't know how to write a CSS rule that can indirect through a for= attribute.

Do I need to whip out the Javascript on this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They don't need to be nested, that's what the "for" attribute is for in the <label> element.

In modern browsers (those supporting CSS 2.1), you can use a sibling selector, such as

```
input + label {
  /* rules */
}
```

You would have to have your markup in a strict sibling relationship, such as:

```
<input name="cb" id="cb" type="checkbox"><label for="cb">Checkbox</label>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about sibling selectors (but I should have).  This would be perfect, except in this one case it needs to work in IE6, which doesn't seem to support them.  Back to JS it is.  :-(

Comment: Yeah, IE6 is a cross I have to drag through the world every day, too. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Using the adjacent/sibling selector plus the attribute selector would make it work:

```
<form>
    <style>
    INPUT[checked=checked] + LABEL {
        color: #f00;    
    }
    </style>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
        <label for="chk1">Label #1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" checked="checked" />
        <label for="chk2">Label #2</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this thing work you need to put the `label` after the `input`, this goes for text type inputs, so `for checkbox you can skip this`, unless you want the label before checkbox.

To keep the order for `label` being shown before the `input` you need to use Flexbox and reverse order of items, for example like this.

```
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

The `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: column-reverse;` reorders the divs content.

Now all you need to do is use this to affect your `label` style.

```
input:checked + label {
  color: #000;
}
```

And HTML for completeness.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberPwd" id="rememberPwd" class="form-input" required/>
        <label for="rememberPwd">Remember?</label>
</div>
```