# Label background-color based on input state

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

i’m working on a tab, trying to highlight the label of the actived content-section. I want to change label's background-color to distinguish the selected tab, is it possible to do that only with css? If not, how can i do that with javascript?
I try with css following this ticket ([Style a <label> based on its <input>'s state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344273/style-a-label-based-on-its-inputs-state)), javascript to assign active state to an element without success.

```css
/* Tabs Name Container */
.TabsHeader-container{
   position: relative;
   width: 120px;
 float: left;
   z-index: 20;
}
/* Tabs Names Label */
.TabsHeader-container label{
   position: relative;
   padding: 10px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   display: block;
   font-size: 13px;
   color: black;
   cursor: pointer;
   user-select: none;
}


.TabsHeader-container1 {
  background-color:#f8ab1f;
  width:50px;
   height:50px;
  border-radius:50px;
}

.TabsHeader-container2 {
  background-color:#f8ab1f;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:50px;
   height:50px;
  border-radius:6px;
}

/* Hover effect on tabs names */
.TabsHeader-container label:hover{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Content area for tabs */
.TabsHeader-content{
  position: relative;
   background: white;
  border-radius:10px;
   width: calc(100% - 120px);
   padding: 15px;
   float: left;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 19;
   display: none;
}
.TabsHeader-content:after{
   content: "";
   clear: both;
}

/* Hide input radio from users */
input[name="TabsHeader"]{
   display: none;
}
/* Show tab when input checked */
input[name="TabsHeader"]:checked + .TabsHeader-content{
   display: block;
   animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
}

/* Slide animation for tab contents */
@keyframes slide{
   from{
     left: -10%;
     opacity: 0;
   }
   to{
     left: 0;
     opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

```html
<section class="TabsHeader-container">
   <label class="TabsHeader-container1" for="TabsHeader1"></label>
   <label class="TabsHeader-container2" for="TabsHeader2"></label>
</section>

<input name="TabsHeader" id="TabsHeader1" type="radio" checked />
<section class="TabsHeader-content">
   <p class="text1" style="font-size:19px;">Your content goes here. Edit or remove this text inline or in the module Content settings. You can also style every aspect of this content in the module Design settings and even apply custom CSS to this text in the module Advanced settings.</p>
   <!-- Any other content -->
</section>
<input class="text2" name="TabsHeader" id="TabsHeader2" type="radio" checked />
<section class="TabsHeader-content">
   <p style="font-size:19px;"> Your content goes here. Edit or remove this text inline or in the module Content settings. You can also style every aspect of this content in the module Design settings and even apply custom CSS to this text in the module Advanced settings.</p>
</section>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Could just use a bit of jquery? something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.TabsHeader-container1').click(function(){
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $('.TabsHeader-container2').removeClass("active");
     });
     $('.TabsHeader-container2').click(function(){
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $('.TabsHeader-container1').removeClass("active");
     });
});
```

Then just add .active{} to your stylesheet with your desired background colour and all should be good.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've copied the javascript code and add ".active{background-color:black}" to the css editor. I also try ".TabsHeader-container2 .active{background-color:black}" and other but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you imported JQuery into your main HTML file?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahdnzj52/ - here's it all working

Comment: Ok, it works partially. Adding JQuery script to the <head> and ".TabsHeader-container2 .active{background-color:black}" to the css editor, the background changes (i don't know why, if i use only .active, it doesn't work). The problem is that javascript chages the color only once the label was clicked. When the page is loaded the label of the actived section is not highlighted.

Comment: Just add the class=“active” to the first label to start with - when someone then clicks one it will remove and re-add the classes anyway

Comment: Have you seen my example jsfiddle above?

Comment: actually - this one is better https://jsfiddle.net/h1pet3nf/

Comment: Sorry, this solution works but get in conflict with theme's icons and sliders. Once the JQuery script was entered (whether it's in the <head>, or in the page, or in the funtion.php file) icons and sliders disappear. So...I need to solve the problem without using jQuery script. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah its because .active is a common used class in many templates unfortunately you didn't provide the rest of your code. Just change .active to .tabactive or something and it would stop this isssue.

Comment: i try...once the JQuery script was deleted, the tabs works, but the .tabactive class no. The tabactive class doesn't effect the style of the other element, it seems to work only with the assigned label (in your fiddle's HTML, the class TabsHeader2). So. the results is that one label is always highlighted, the other one never (p.s. if i do the same thing on your fiddle page, everything works).

Comment: See this: https://jsfiddle.net/x1sacbdh/ - you have to change it in the HTML, jQuery and CSS

Comment: It is exactly what i've done. it doesn't work. To be sure, i recopying the code of your last fiddle. Nothing. Without JQuery script the tabactive doesn't work on the other label.