# CSS syntax for merging two conditions

Tags: css

I have HTML structure that looks like -

```
<div class="form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">TEXT A
  </label>
</div>
```

I want that when the input type is checked (checked being the inbuilt class that is added automatically on checking the radio button ), I apply a style before label.

In unchecked case -

```
label::before{
  /* something */
}
```

In checked case, I am writing something like this,

```
input[type='radio']:checked label::before{
  /* something */
}
```

I want to apply **label::before** where **input[type='radio']:checked** but I don't know how to merge these two conditions in CSS. I just need help with the syntax.

Can anyone please tell me ?

Thanks !!

Comment: CSS doesn't allow to style a parent based on its child. But it does allow to style an element based on its previous sibling using the `+` combinator. If you decide to go that route, you'd have to change your markup like so: `<label>text</label> <input>`.

Comment: Sorry, wrong order, the input would need to be first: `<input> <label>text</label>`, then you could change the visual order using `flex-direction: row-reverse`.

Comment: Couple of examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344273/style-a-label-based-on-its-inputs-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Use `for` attribute on label instead of nesting input inside of the label in order to use the the adjacent sibling combinator.

### Example

#### HTML

```
<div class="form-check-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">

    <label class="form-check-label" for=“optradio”>
        TEXT A
    </label>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
input[type='radio']:checked + label::before{
   /* something */
}
```

## References

Adjacent sibling combinator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Comment: I have a follow up question on this.  I am  unable to toggle between the styles for checked and unchecked. For example, the style for current checked radio should be undone if I click on next unchecked radio. But unable to do that. Is there a way this can be handled through CSS alone? ( I am adding an image before label )

Comment: @ItykaBandta style the default without the checked as you want it and it should apply.

Comment: Yes. I did that... I don't know what I am missing. Please check my fiddle . (the icons wont display ! you can try with random images) https://jsfiddle.net/woke_mushroom/2sjypnor/20/

Comment: @ItykaBandta you need to include the input piece for the default behavior without checked due to specificity of the adjacent sibling operator overriding label default without the adjacent sibling operator.

Comment: I added this - input[type=radio] + label::before {} for default behavior. But nothing :(

Comment: @ItykaBandta your code in js fiddle works for me, which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. I spot the mistake now ! I had been using same id for both the labels ! Thanks though !!!